# What is the difference between context.Add() and context.Entity.add() in Entity Framework Core 7?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

When I want to add a new data set to my database via Entity Framework Core I first create the entity and fill it with data and then I can either call `context.Add(entityData);` OR `context.Entity.Add(entityData);` I have seen code examples doing it both ways, the official Microsoft documentation  does it the second way but I can't find anything explaining the different. Looking at the Visual Studio code hints it looks like they are the same. Is there any functional difference between the two and if so when would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DbSet.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.add?view=efcore-7.0)

> Begins tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked, in the Added state such that they will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges() is called.

And [`DbContext.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-7.0)

> Begins tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked, in the Added state such that they will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges() is called.

Do the same thing.

Actually the implementations looks the same - [`DbSet` via `InternalDbSet`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/767bc93c6e6fca19868f486c7df8f4235bcf53cd/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs#L187) and [`DbContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/767bc93c6e6fca19868f486c7df8f4235bcf53cd/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L1223) via [`SetEntityState`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/767bc93c6e6fca19868f486c7df8f4235bcf53cd/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L1421).

Comment: Thanks that is what I though from reading the tool tips in VS (which have the statements you quoted) but I wanted to make sure I was not missing anything.